# What is the sum of the cube of the roots of $ x^3 + x^2 - 2x + 1=0$?

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, roots, symmetric-polynomials

I know there are roots, because if we assume the equation as a function and give -3 and 1 as $x$:

$$
(-3)^3 + (-3)^2 - 2(-3) + 1 <0
$$

$$
1^3 + 1^2 - 2(1) + 1 > 0
$$

It [must have a root between $[-3,1]$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem). However, [the root is very hard](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E3+%2B+x%5E2+-+2x+%2B+1+%3D+0&dataset=&asynchronous=false&equal=Submit) and it appeared on a high school test. How can I solve it simply?

The given options were -10, -5, 0 , 5 and 10. Note: we didn't even learn the cube root formula. The test had just logic problems and I didn't use any calculus or complicated stuff. So there must be an easier way without using cube root concepts or formulas.

Comment: Are you sure you have to *find the sum of the cube of the roots*?

Comment: A quick search provided some useful information I think: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30491/sum-of-cubed-roots

Comment: A [hint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Application_to_the_characteristic_polynomial_of_a_matrix)

Comment: Lol 3 answers exactly same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using the information in the equation
$$
\sum_{i=1}^3 r_i^3 = -\sum_{i=1}^3 (r_i^2 - 2r_i + 1) \\
= -5 -\sum_{i=1}^3 r_i^2
$$
also, from the well-known expressions giving the elementary symmetric functions of the roots in terms of the coefficients,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^3 r_i^2 = (\sum_{i=1}^3 r_i)^2 - 2(r_1r_2+r_2r_3+r_3r_1) \\
= 5
$$
so the sum of cubes of the roots is $-10$

Comment: David, can you explain step by step?

Comment: if $r$ is a root, then $r^3 = -r^2+2r-1$. a cubic has three roots (in an algebraically closed field), so we can sum this relation over the roots $r_1,r_2,r_3$. the constant term $-1$ gives $-3$. the sum of the roots is minus the coefficient of $x^2$ divided by the coefficient of $x^3$, so the $2r$ term gives a sum of $-2$. the $r^2$ term is obtained by the method shown,  where the sum of the products of the roots in pairs is the ratio of the coefficient of $x$ to that of $x^3$. check out one of the references in other answers to "relations between roots" etc.

Comment: Perfect! You did it.

Answer (score 5):

You know,

$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ca)$

$a^3+b^3+c^3=(a+b+c)[(a+b+c)^2-3(ab+bc+ca)]+3abc$

Now I hope you know the [relation between roots.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88917/relation-betwen-coefficients-and-roots-of-a-polynomial)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $a,b,c\in\mathbb{C}$ are the roots to your equation. There is this algebraic identity you should know:
$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)$$
Do some manipulations to get this form:
$$a^3+b^3+c^3=3abc+(a+b+c)\left((a+b+c)^2-3(ab+bc+ca)\right)$$

> [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas) are formulas that relate the coefficients of a polynomial to sums and products of its roots.

Comment: I'm curious: is there any relationship with $ (x-1)^2 $ ?

Comment: @Lucas maybe. i don't see one

Comment: Take a look at the note.

Comment: @LucasHenrique this is the easiest way I can think of. It does *not* involve any calculus. The algebraic identity seems simple enough and as for Vieta's formulas, I am confident that someone your age can understand that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use Newton's formulas and Vieta's formulas 
https://brilliant.org/wiki/newtons-identities/

Comment: I think the link is to newton

Comment: Thnx its ok now