# How many real, rational and complex solutions has this system of equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, systems-of-equations

Let the system $\left\{\begin{aligned} 
      a+b+c &= 3\\ 
     a^2+b^2+c^2 &=5\\
a^3+b^3+c^3 & =12
    \end{aligned}\right. $

**How many real, rational and complex solutions has it?**

I read [System of three variables of simultaneous equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27394/three-variable-system-of-simultaneous-equations?noredirect=1&lq=1) and found $ e_1 = 3, e_2 = 2, e_3 = 1 $. Then I do not understand the reason but I get the polynomial $ t ^ 3-3t ^ 2 + 2t-1 $. The question is how many , not what are the solutions, so at this point I do not know what to do ...  or if I'm in the right way.  Can you help me please?

Comment: So, how many real, rational and complex solutions are there for the polynomial $t^3-3t^2+2t-1$?

Comment: You just have to see if the equation $t^3-3t^2+2t-1=0$ has three roots over the rationals, over the reals and over the complexes. I'll start you off. It does have three roots over the complexes. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: You way is right. Now, show that your equation has an unique real root.

Comment: For the *rational* part, you may apply the rational root theorem. For the remaining part, it is enough to compute the discriminant of such polynomial, or locate its stationary points.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown and they're https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=t%5E3-3t%5E2%2B2t-1%3D0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note
$$ 3^2=(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ca=5+2(ab+bc+ca). $$
from this, one has
$$ ab+bc+ca=2. $$
Also
\begin{eqnarray}
3^3&=&(a+b+c)^3=a^3+b^3+c^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+3a^2c+3ac^2+3b^2c+3bc^2+6abc\\
&=&12+3ab(a+b+c)+3bc(a+b+c)+3ca(a+b+c)-3abc\\
&=&12+3(ab+bc+ca)(a+b+c)-3abc\\
&=&30-3abc
\end{eqnarray}
from which, one has
$$ abc=1. $$
Thus $a,b$ and $c$ are the roots of the following equation
$$ t^3-3t^2+2t-1=0. \tag{1} $$
So the coefficients of (1) are
$$ a_3=1,a_2=-3,a_1=2,a_0=-1 $$
and hence the discriminant is
$$ \Delta=18a_3a_2a_1a_0-4a_2^3a_0+a_2^2a_1^2-4a_3a_1^3-27a_3^2a_0^2=-23<0$$
and hence (1) has one real root and two complex roots.

Comment: But what is the nature of the roots?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, see the update.

Answer (score 0):

It has 6 solutions

Here they are

$$a_1 = 2.32472$$
$$b_1 = 0.56228·i+0.337641$$
$$c_1 = 0.337641−0.56228·i$$
$$a_2 = 2.32472$$
$$b_ 2= 0.337641−0.56228·i$$
$$c_2 = 0.56228·i+0.337641$$
$$a_3 = 0.337641−0.56228·i$$
$$b_3 = 0.56228·i+0.337641$$
$$c_3 = 5.118e−18·i+2.32472$$
$$a_4 = 0.337641−0.56228·i$$
$$b_4 = 1.11022e−16·i+2.32472$$
$$c_4 = 0.56228·i+0.337641$$
$$a_5 = 0.56228·i+0.337641$$
$$b_5 = 0.337641−0.56228·i$$
$$c_5 = 1.69412e−18·i+2.32472$$

Comment: I don't believe $c_3\ddot\smile$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Why don't you believe $c_3$

Comment: It should be the same as $b_6$, yet its imaginary part is completely different!

Comment: Sorry for that it has 5 solutions

Comment: It really does have six solutions for $(a,b,c)\ \ddot\frown$.

Comment: How did you find it?